# No message when flagging a comment

Tags: feature-request, flags, comment-flags, error-message

When I flag a question or answer, I get this:

> [image: Thanks, we'll take a look at it]

When I flag a comment, I get this:

> 

No confirmation that the ajax request was successful. Nothing.

Can we have a message when we flag comments?

Comment: I'm not going to like seeing popups after every comment I flag. If you really want to be sure, hovering over the same comment reveals a red version of the flag and absence of the upvote button.

Answer (score 3):

This has since been implemented ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)).